# nodejs latest version installation error on ubuntu 18.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, node.js

i have used the following commands for node js installation

sudo apt install curl
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash -
sudo apt install nodejs

3rd command gives the following error

> The following packages have unmet dependencies: nodejs : Depends:
>   python-minimal but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to
>   correct problems, you have held broken packages.

i have found many solutions on the internet but none of them works for me, yes i am new to linux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pixelbook installing r-base dependency with held broken packages error](https://superuser.com/questions/1422059/pixelbook-installing-r-base-dependency-with-held-broken-packages-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUboP.png)
Just reset the main repository to "Main server" of Ubuntu or another distribution of Linux 
and then run the below commands:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```